# pandoc error in finding image file

Tags: r, pdf, knitr, r-markdown, pandoc

Just wanted to insert two images in to the rmarkdown pdf document.  When knitting it gives the error

> pandoc.exe: Could not find image `paste0(Figs,%20%22Fig1.png%22)',
>   skipping... pandoc.exe: Unable to convert`
>   paste0(Figs,%20%22Fig1.png%22)' for use with pdflatex. ! Missing
>   \endcsname inserted.

Below is the code

````html
---
title: "Some title"
author: Arvin
date: "October 20, 2016"
output: pdf_document
fig_caption: yes
---
```{r, echo=FALSE}

Figs <- 'C:/Users/arvin/Figs/'
```
![Fig1](paste0(Figs, "Fig1.png"))
````

I used knitr_1.14 and r_markdown_1.0.

Answer (score 2):

It is clear, why your code does not work: you used the function `paste` outside the R-environment. So pandoc searches for `paste0(Figs,%20%22Fig1.png%22)` as a filename.

You can't do it in this way you wanna do this. The regular usage is

```
---
title: "Some title"
author: Arvin
date: "October 20, 2016"
output: 
  pdf_document:
    fig_caption: yes
---

![Fig1](C:/Users/arvin/Figs/Fig1.png)
```

**BUT** there is another solution, where you have the full control of image size, and you can plot like a regular R plot, using `grid.raster` from the `grid` package. And here your approach will work, because we are in a R environment:

````
```{r fig.width=10, fig.height=10, echo=FALSE}
library(png)
library(grid)

Figs <- 'C:/Users/arvin/Figs/'

img <- readPNG(paste0(Figs, "Fig1.png"))
 grid.raster(img)
```
````

Answer (score 2):

Inline R code should be put in `` `r ` ``:

````
---
title: "Some title"
author: Arvin
date: "October 20, 2016"
output:
  pdf_document
    fig_caption: yes
---

```{r, echo=FALSE}
Figs <- 'C:/Users/arvin/Figs/'
```

![Fig1](`r paste0(Figs, "Fig1.png")`)
````

BTW, an unsolicited pro-tip: Do not use absolute paths. Use relative paths.